# TeamCity Github issue

Tags: git, github, teamcity

when i am trying to create a VCS root of git repo in my root project in teamcity. It is giving me a weird error on Testing connection. The error says:

```
Cannot find revision of the default branch 'master' of vcs root "jetbrains.git"
{instance id=30, parent internal id=-1, parent id=dummy_jetbrains.git,
description: <my git repo URL>
```

[image: error on testing git repo conn]

this error is driving me insane and i cannot fix this issue. i can clone and push changes to my repo the usual way in cmd line with git cmd.

my git repo is a public repo on github and I am using master as default branch.

Do I need to do something in my github settings?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't have enough points to write this as a comment, but these are some things that I think you should check:

Path to Git: This box is empty in your VCS root configuration, so Teamcity is defaulting to TEAMCITY_GIT_PATH. Have you tried explicitly setting to the directory of your build agent's git installation?

URL: Are you specifying the https URL for github? https://github.com/yourname/repo.git

Did you just create the repository on Github?  You'll also want to make sure that the master branch exists on the remote.

Finally, you can look at the TeamCity server log. This will give you a bit more detail as to why you can't connect.

Answer (score 0):

One simple that fixed that issue by creating a branch named "master" in git.I figured that teamcity is looking for master branch.

Answer (score 0):

What fixed this for me was the casing of the VCS route I was trying to connect to was all lower case, but in TeamCity I had it capitalized